# How to hit a web page programmatically and silently?

Tags: language-agnostic

I would like to know how can I hit a web page programmatically and silently using C/C++?

I tried ShellExecute (shellapi.h), don't know how to make use of it?

Comment: could you explain what you mean by 'silently' ?

Comment: not showing window...I just want to figure out from which IP the server is serving?

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTTP protocol directly

1. netcat
2. curl
3. wget
4. [HTTP Client Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3wxbf3f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

On linuxen there are perl implemented CLI commands (GET, PUT, POST), in short: pick one from a vast array; you platform will have tools too.

Simplistic example:

```
type request.http | netcat mywebserver:80
```

Where request.http could be as simple as

```
GET /
```

(mind the trailing empty lines, which SO helpfully hides)